# SQL условие только для внешней таблицы

Tags: php, sql, yii

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
field
 -id
 -title
field_val
 -id
 -field_id
 -user_id
```

Задача: 
сделать выборку всех полей таблицы `field` со связной таблицей `field_val`, тип связи `OUTER`.

Но задать для внешней таблицы `field_val` дополнительное условие `field_val.user_id = x` . И, если поле со условием `field_val.user_id = x` не существует, то выводить `NULL`, сохраняя поле с первой таблицы.

Проблема в том, если в таблице `field_val` не существует поля `user_id` со значением `Х`, то и поле таблицы `field` так же не выводится.

Пример того, что у меня получилось, но не работает приводить не буду, т.к запрос составляю для AR в YII.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  f.*,
  v.*
FROM
  field AS f
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  field_val AS v
ON
  f.id = v.field_id AND
  v.user_id = x
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но оформить criteria в yii так и не удалось, пришлось использовать DAO